# How can i find the tip of a pointer meter?

Tags: python, opencv, contour, hough-transform

I would like to draw a line from the center of the clock to the tip of the pointer. I can find the center of the clock by the following code:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
                      param1=50, param2=35, minRadius=10,
                      maxRadius=46)

data = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for (x, y ,r) in data[0, :]:
    cv2.circle(img2, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), 1) #center
```

But I can't understand how to find and draw the line at the tip of the pointer.

Here is the code i got:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
img = cv2.imread('meter-3.jpg')

# Applying filters to facilitate detection of circles and contours

img = cv2.blur(img,(3,3))
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
img_erosion = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_dilation, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            

# Detection of circles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
                        param1=50, param2=35, minRadius=10,
                        maxRadius=46)

date = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for (x, y ,r) in data[0, :]:
    cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), 1) #center

ROIs = {}

# Fix array to INT
circles = circles.reshape(-1,3).astype(np.int16)

for e, c in enumerate(circles):
  # Coordinates of the center of the circle and its radius
  x_c, y_c, R = c[0], c[1], c[2]
  x = x_c - R
  y = y_c - R
  w = x_c + R
  h = y_c + R

  # Crop each pointer into a new image
  ROI = img[y:h,x:w]

  ROI = cv2.blur(ROI,(3,3))

  # Outline detection
  edges_roi = cv2.Canny(ROI, 320, 125)
  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges_roi, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
  black = np.zeros_like(ROI)
  cnt = contours[0]

  for e,con in enumerate(contours):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(con)
    # Filters out outlines smaller than 25 pixels
    if w < 25 or h < 25:
      continues
    cv2.drawContours(black,[con],-1, (0.255,0),1)
    cv2.imshow('Black',black)
    cv2.rectangle(ROI,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

    # Add ROI to Dictionary
    ROIs[str(e)] = [ROI]

  cv2.imshow('ROI',ROI)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the result i get:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKkow.png)

Can anyone help me at this coding process, please?

Thanks

Comment: that's a blurry/low-res picture. expect nothing out of a blurry/low-res picture. get a better picture. -- usual solution: locate the dial (circle/ellipse), polar transform and take a scanline (i.e. circular band in source), "plot" brightness, find the dip that is the indicator -- I can't be bothered to find previous questions but there are some. post a better picture (not cropped, not upsampled) if you're hoping for a demonstration